# please how can i create a click on each tiles to make a game sequences?

Tags: javascript, css

The page consists of a board of tiles (default 4x4).
- every 2 tiles have the same color (it could be an image, user should select 2 tiles with the same color to make them disappear. If he selects 2 tiles with different colors then they are flipped to "closed" state, and user proceeds with the next round.

Javascript

```
var a=document.getElementById(main).onclick="f()"; 
var b= document.getElementById("1").onclick="f()"; 
var b= document.getElementById("2").onclick="f()"; 
var d= document.getElementById("3").onclick="f()"; 
var i=0; if(i=="tile1" || i=="tile2"){ i=0 } else{ i++ } } }
```

HTML

```
<div id="main"> 
<div id="1"></div> 
<div id="2"></div> 
<div id="3"></div> 
<div id="e4"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Post what you have tried so we can help.  What does default(4X4) mean?

Comment: var a=document.getElementById("tile1").onclick="f()";
var b= document.getElementById("tile2").onclick="f()";
var b= document.getElementById("tile3").onclick="f()";
var d= document.getElementById("tile4").onclick="f()";
var i=0;
    if(i=="tile1" || i=="tile2"){
        i=0
    }
    else{
        i++
    }
}
}

Comment: <div id="main">
            <div id="tile1"></div>
            <div id="tile2"></div>
            <div id="tile3"></div>
            <div id="tile4"></div>
        </div>

Comment: Update your question. Do not paste your raw code in a comment

Comment: ar a=document.getElementById(main).onclick="f()"; 
var b= document.getElementById("1").onclick="f()"; 
var b= document.getElementById("2").onclick="f()"; 
var d= document.getElementById("3").onclick="f()"; 
var i=0; if(i=="tile1" || i=="tile2"){ i=0 } else{ i++ } } }
HTML

<div id="main"> 
<div id="1"></div> 
<div id="2"></div> 
<div id="3"></div> 
<div id="4"></div> 
</div>

Comment: please how can i create a click function on a tiles of a games sequences

Comment: i added an answer, i think, but not sure what you want to happen when you click the div. hope it helps

Comment: yes i got it,  what i mean by  a tiles of 4X4 image is a sort of  gameplay  sequence of rounds. and when a user click on the image the  tile is closed, so user can not see a color,but  when a  user  then select 2 tiles with the same color the image them disappear.. the tiles are considered to be over when all of the tiles are opened.? can you help??

Answer (score 0):

I added an function to be triggered by onclick.  This just changes color so you will have to adjust this to meet your needs.  Hope it helps.

```js
function f() {
  document.getElementById('tile1').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function f2() {
  document.getElementById('tile2').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function f3() {
  document.getElementById('tile3').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function f4() {
  document.getElementById('tile4').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
#tile1,
#tile2,
#tile3,
#tile4 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px #000000 solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div onclick="f();" id="tile1"></div>
  <div onclick="f2();" id="tile2"></div>
  <div onclick="f3();" id="tile3"></div>
  <div onclick="f4();" id="tile4"></div>
</div>
```

in essence as you click on the div it runs a function that changes the color.